# How to use transformers from nodejs script

Tags: python, node.js, huggingface-transformers

I would like to use transformers in my Python code from NodeJs but it is not working without showing any error. Just by importing transformers my code isn't working. Of course by removing that part, the code runs smoothly.

NodeJs code

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["./SentAnalysis.py", JSON.stringify(reviewsArray)]);

pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString())
   });
```

Python code

```
from transformers import pipeline
import json
import sys

reviewsStr = sys.argv[1]

reviewsArray = reviewsStr.strip('][').split(', ')

sentiment_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
results = sentiment_pipeline(reviewsArray)


print(''.join(results))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python usually gives errors but Python3 always get the job done. Although Python also has transformers package, it did not run in this instance. So replacing "python" with "python3" in the spawn process in nodeJs code worked like a charm.